# JavaScript or Lodash find objects by key

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

In an array of objects with diff keys, how do I find objects by key using ES6 or Lodash?

```
const arr = [{a:2}, {b:3}, {fred:10}]
```

I want the result to be:

```
=> [{a:2}, {fred:10}]
```

I don't want to use an omit style approach.

Comment: How do you go from your `arr` to your result?

Comment: thats the question

Comment: No, that's not the question. You want to find objects by key, that's the question. Your results just kind of come from thin air. What the criteria? How do you get that result?

Comment: why is your result `arr` without the middle element? what is the logic of this magic trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you want all the objects from the array who have the fields `a` or `fred`. You can use the `hasOwnProperty()` on the objects while filtering.

```
_.filter(array, elem => elem.hasOwnProperty('a') || elem.hasOwnProperty('fred'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
const filtered = arr.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty("a") || obj.hasOwnProperty("fred"));

// or, if you have dynamic / lots of keys:
const keys = ["a", "fred"];
const filtered = arr.filter(obj => keys.some(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key));
```

Answer (score 1):

filter method will be useful. Create a function and pass an array of `keys`. Inside filter function check if the key  is matching with the parameter array. If it passed then return that object

```js
var orgObject = [{
  a: 2
}, {
  b: 3
}, {
  fred: 10
}];

function searchByKey(keyNames) {

  return orgObject.filter(function(item) {
    for (var keys in item) {
      if (keyNames.indexOf(keys) !== -1) {
        return item
      }
    }
  })
}


console.log(searchByKey(['a', 'fred']))
```